# Visual Studio suddenly wants me to declare loop iterators

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I've been happily writing code like this:

```
For idtArticles = 0 To dtArticles.Rows.Count - 1
```

and this:

```
If request.QueryString.HasKeys() Then
    For Each parameter In request.QueryString.AllKeys
        requestVars.Add(parameter, request.QueryString(parameter))
    Next
Else...
```

And suddenly it won't compile and giving errors

> Error 34  'idtArticles' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to
>   its protection level. ..userAccountModel.vb

Which assuming I can't go back to my lazy ways is fine to edit as

```
 For idtArticles as Integer
```

But I don't know for exampple what the Request collection would be declared as..

> Error 39  'Parameter' is a type and cannot be used as an
>   expression.   ..userAccountModel.vb

How can I make it go back to not caring?  Also if not, what shall I `DIM` that `Parameter` as?

I've checked and Option Strict is OFF.  In **Tools..** Default Project Settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Is dtArticles public?

Comment: [`'Parameter' is a type...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter(v=vs.110).aspx) use something like `p` or `parm` and it should work.  The fact that VS/VB **can** get confused with what you are doing in your code, should give you pause about turning Option Strict Off.  It is worth noting that Option Infer would allow `For idtArticles = 0`; the type would be inferred from the context

Comment: @max dtArticles is declared just moments before and not available outside the Sub

Comment: @Plutonix I've changed the Parameter line to  ´For Each p As String In request.QueryString.AllKeys´  I can't test it because there's 101 build errors now its got all finicky on me.  Do you think that will work?  The swiggles have gone anyway. It was iterating the Request Object happily before.

Comment: ...as before, that should give you pause about writing code without Option Strict  (101 or 102 is the max it shows at one time, fix 10 and ten new ones might be added to the list).

Comment: This question has been "downvoted" - apparently "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"... Well thanks!  I put about 1 hr into writing it after googling for 6, I put all my code that I'd tried, and it certainly was useful getting the answer.  So I'm at loss as to why it was "downvoted".  Would the "downvoter" care to explain?

Comment: You should really have Option Strict On.  It will make your code better in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Microsoft Doc on [Option Infer Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx):

> When you set **Option Infer** to **On**, you can declare local variables
>   without explicitly stating a data type. The compiler infers the data
>   type of a variable from the type of its initialization expression.

I would try this at the top of your code file:

```
Option Infer On
```

Or, alternatively you can change this on My Project -> Compile - Option Infer, right under Option strict!

[image]

Comment: Yes that was it.  Error 1: I was looking at Option Strict.  And Error 2: I was looking at the Defaults in Tools.. Options...  The project once created is set as in this answer.  Thanks all!

Comment: +1 Very nice. I didn't know that because i always declare my variables.